How to edit default colors based on Bootstrap theme?
I want to change variables such as primary, success, body-bg especially for dark and light themes using sass in Bootstrap, but I couldn't find the right way. Can you help?
What I'm trying to do is something like this:
@include color-mode(light) {
  $primary: #696cff;
  $secondary: #8492a2;
  $success: #70dc38;
  $danger: #ff3e1d;
  $warning: #ffab00;
  $info: #02c3eb;
  $body-bg: #f4f4f8;
  $card-bg: #fff;
}

@include color-mode(dark) {
  $primary: #5f62e7;
  $secondary: #8492a2;
  $success: #70dc38;
  $danger: #ff3e1d;
  $warning: #ffab00;
  $info: #02c3eb;
  $body-bg: #232333;
  $card-bg: #2a2b41;
}

